# Unable to click checkbox of System Preferences by AppleScript, although it doesn't show errors

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-mojave

### Errors

I had written the code below, and it seems to work until it select the row.

However, `click checkbox` doesn't work even though it doesn't give any errors.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "System Preferences"
        repeat while not (window 1 exists)
        end repeat
    tell window 1

    repeat while not (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)
    end repeat

    repeat with current_row in (rows of table 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1)
        if value of static text 1 of current_row is equal to "Input Sources" then
            select current_row
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    repeat while not (rows of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1 exists)
    end repeat

    repeat with current_row in rows of outline 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of tab group 1
        if name of UI element 2 of current_row is equal to "Select next source in input menu" then
            select current_row
            click checkbox of current_row
            exit repeat
        end if
    end repeat

    end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

### What I have tried

I wrote below alternatively, but they all not work.

```
set value of checkbox of selected_row
set checkbox of selected_row to true
```

### References

I searched many articles, but it doesn't solve.

[How to click a checkbox of a drop-down tab in System Preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196697/how-to-click-a-checkbox-of-a-drop-down-tab-in-system-preferences)

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20040317131326880

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
click checkbox of current_row
```

To:

```
click checkbox of UI element 1 of current_row
```

Tested your script on macOS Mojave, making the change shown above, and it worked as desired.

Comment: OMG, it worked. I tried 3 days into this.... I really thank you. Perhaps, could you tell me how to learn the structure of system preferences? There is no document about it, and there is no way to check it not like Inspection of Browser......

Comment: I found the way. Using every UI elements can get all elements. thank you.